# Extracting ALL matches of a nested regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse a list of items which satisfies the python regex

```
r'\A(("[\w\s]+"|\w+)\s+)*\Z'
```

that is, it's a space separated list except that spaces are allowed inside quoted strings. I would like to get a list of items in the list (that is of items matched by the

```
r'("[\w\s]+"|\w+)'
```

part. So, for example

```
>>> parse('foo "bar baz" "bob" ')
['foo', '"bar baz"', '"bob"']
```

Is there any nice way to do this with python re?

Many things don't quite work. For example

```
>>> re.match(r'\A(("[\w\s]+"|\w+)\s+)*\Z', 'foo "bar baz" "bob" ').group(2)
'"bob"'
```

only returns the last one it matched. On the other hand

```
>>> re.findall(r'("[\w\s]+"|\w+)', 'foo "bar baz" "bob" ')
['foo', '"bar baz"', '"bob"']
```

but it also accepts malformed expressions like

```
>>> re.findall(r'("[\w\s]+"|\w+)', 'foo "bar b-&&az" "bob" ')
['foo', 'bar', 'b', 'az', '" "', 'bob']
```

So is there any way to use the original regex and get all of the items that matched group 2? Something like

```
>>> re.match_multigroup(r'\A(("[\w\s]+"|\w+)\s+)*\Z', 'foo "bar baz" "bob" ').group(2)
['foo', '"bar baz"', '"bob"']
>>> re.match_multigroup(r'("[\w\s]+"|\w+)', 'foo "bar b-&&az" "bob" ')
None
```

Edit: It **is** important that I preserve the quotes in the output, thus I don't want

```
>>> re.match_multigroup(r'\A(("[\w\s]+"|\w+)\s+)*\Z', 'foo "bar baz" "bob" ').group(2)
['foo', 'bar baz', 'bob']
```

because then I don't know if bob was quoted or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I ended up deciding to do this in two steps.

First I check that the expression is syntactically valid and second I break it into individual pieces:

```
def parse(expr):
    if re.match(r'\A(("[\w\s]+"|\w+)\s+)*\Z', expr):
        return re.findall(r'("[\w\s]+"|\w+)', expr)
```

So:

```
>>> parse('foo "bar baz" "bob" ')
['foo', '"bar baz"', '"bob"']
>>> parse('foo "bar b-&&az" "bob" ')
>>> parse('foo "bar" ')
['foo', '"bar"']
>>> parse('"foo" bar ')
['"foo"', 'bar']
>>> parse('foo"bar baz" "bob" ')
>>> parse('&&')
```

I'm about 90% sure that this method works appropriately for all strings, but I would still be interested if anyone had a more general solution, this seems sort of kludgey to me.

Thanks SilentGhost and Alan Moore for the help. I did not know about python csv or regex lookaheads before, it might be helpful to me to learn about those.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that regex is the right tool here. Try [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module:

```
>>> s = 'foo "bar baz" "bob" '
>>> for i in csv.reader([s], delimiter=' '):
    print(i)


['foo', 'bar baz', 'bob', '']
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However in my application, I need to distinguish between items that are quoted and ones that aren't, where as this doesn't seem to do that.

Comment: and what is the purpose of this requirement?

Comment: I am parsing a specification. The specification is a list of two types of things (unquoted things) and (quoted things). They need to be treated differently, so they need to be distinguishable. If you like replace " with * or & or some other character, it's just delimiting the second type of thing. Sorry for the non-standard notation.

Comment: can't you tell which should be quoted from the order?

Comment: no, they could be in any order. For example:

    'foo bob '
    'foo "bob" '
    '"foo" bob '
    '"foo" "bob" '

are all valid inputs that should be mutually destinguishable

Comment: may be I'm mistaken but you input doesn't seem to be regular.

Comment: It's a little weird, but consider it to be an expression which mixes strings and variables. Thus 'foo "bar"' is the variable foo and the string "bar", I need to distinguish that foo is a variable and "bar" is a string.

Comment: What do you mean? Of course there is an order in the expression, but variables and strings could be in any order. Like I said, 'foo "bar"' and '"foo" bar' are both allowed but distinguishable. The first has variable foo then string "bar" the second had string "foo" then variable bar.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that splits on any whitespace that isn't inside a pair of quotation marks:

```
re.split('\s+(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)', target)
```

The lookahead succeeds only if there's an even number of quotation marks ahead of the just-matched whitespace.  If quoted sections in your text can contain escaped quotes, you may need a more complicated regex, depending on how the escaping is done.

Comment: Wow, that seems to work, now if I can just figure out how it works :)

Comment: Er, actually, there is a problem, this never rejects expressions, so if target = 'foo"bar baz" "bob"', it returns ['foo"bar baz"', '"bob"'].

Comment: I suppose I could just check that each output is in the right format and fail if not, though.

Comment: Does your input really contain quoted and non-quoted sections run together like that? None of your examples do.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. But someone could make a typo and so I want to reject strings that don't fit the regex. Thus my example with the quoted and unquoted strings stuck together should be rejected. Likewise other expressions like '&&' should be rejected because they use characters that aren't allowed. Your expression does not verify that the inputs are correct, it just separates them correctly if they are.

Comment: However, like I said, I could easily check each element in the list after using your expression runs and if all of the elements are well-formed, then I think the whole thing must be well-formed. So, no worries.